# Free JqGrid, calculated field is wrongly set to NaN in the footer

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to work out why the percentage number in the field in the corner of this grid is set to NaN. To save you time, look at the JsFiddle here;
https://jsfiddle.net/arame3333/ttc83khL/8/

Alternatively if the link is broken here is the code;
HTML:

```
<body>
    <hi>SIR Tracker - Outstanding Defects Current on 23rd November 2017</hi>
    <div id="outerDiv" style="margin:5px;">
      <table id="treegrid"></table>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div, .ui-jqgrid-sortable  {
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

JQuery/JqGrid:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var thisMonthName = getMonthName();
    var lastMonthName = getLastMonthName();
    var mydata = [
        { id: "1", name: "CD/N142 Janson Close", yearStart: "10", lastMonth: "1",
            thisMonth: "72", outstandingFaults: "83", openFaults: "83", closeFaults: "3", totalFaults: "169",
                  level: "0", parent: "null", isLeaf: false, expanded: true, loaded: true,
            icon: "ui-icon-folder-open,ui-icon-folder-collapsed" },
        { id: "2", name: "Electrical", yearStart: "8", lastMonth: "1",
            thisMonth: "48", outstandingFaults: "77", openFaults: "43", closeFaults: "2", totalFaults: "109",
            level: "1", parent: "1", isLeaf: true, expanded: false, loaded: true },
        { id: "3", name: "Mechanical", yearStart: "2", lastMonth: "0",
            thisMonth: "24", outstandingFaults: "6", openFaults: "40", closeFaults: "1", totalFaults: "60",
            level: "1", parent: "1", isLeaf: true, expanded: false, loaded: true },
      { id: "4", name: "CD/L224 Lychet Way", yearStart: "3", lastMonth: "10",
            thisMonth: "67", outstandingFaults: "80", openFaults: "130", closeFaults: "265", totalFaults: "475",
                  level: "0", parent: "null", isLeaf: false, expanded: true, loaded: true,
            icon: "ui-icon-folder-open,ui-icon-folder-collapsed" },
        { id: "5", name: "Electrical", yearStart: "2", lastMonth: "8",
            thisMonth: "47", outstandingFaults: "40", openFaults: "80", closeFaults: "190", totalFaults: "270",
            level: "1", parent: "4", isLeaf: true, expanded: false, loaded: true },
        { id: "6", name: "Mechanical", yearStart: "1", lastMonth: "2",
            thisMonth: "20", outstandingFaults: "40", openFaults: "50", closeFaults: "75", totalFaults: "205",
            level: "1", parent: "4", isLeaf: true, expanded: false, loaded: true }
    ];

    $("#treegrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colNames: ["Project", "From year start", lastMonthName, thisMonthName, "Outstanding faults", "Open", "Close", "Total", "% Outstanding"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "name", width: 200 },
            { name: "yearStart", template: "integer", width: 50 },
            { name: "lastMonth", template: "integer", width: 50 },
            { name: "thisMonth", template: "integer", width: 50 },
            { name: "outstandingFaults", template: "integer", width: 80 },
            { name: "openFaults", template: "integer", width: 50 },
            { name: "closeFaults", template: "integer", width: 50 },
            { name: "totalFaults", template: "integer", width: 50 },
            { name: 'faultsPerc', template: "integer", width: 80,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
                         {
                             return Math.round(rowObject["outstandingFaults"] / rowObject["totalFaults"] * 100);
                          }
                        }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
        autoresize: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        treeGrid: true,
        treeGridModel: "adjacency",
        ExpandColumn: "name",
        footerrow: true,
        gridComplete: function() {
          var $grid = $('#treegrid');
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "name": "Total"} );
          var colSumYearStart = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "yearStart", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "yearStart": colSumYearStart });
          var colSumLastMonth = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "lastMonth", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "lastMonth": colSumLastMonth });
          var colSumThisMonth = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "thisMonth", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "thisMonth": colSumThisMonth });
          var colSumOutstandingFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "outstandingFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "outstandingFaults": colSumOutstandingFaults });
          var colSumOpenFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "openFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "openFaults": colSumOpenFaults });
          var colSumCloseFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "closeFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "closeFaults": colSumCloseFaults });
          var colSumCloseFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "closeFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "closeFaults": colSumCloseFaults });
          var colSumTotalFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "totalFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "totalFaults": colSumTotalFaults });
          var avePercentage = colSumOutstandingFaults / colSumTotalFaults * 100;
          $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { "faultsPerc": avePercentage });
      }

    });
});

var populateFooterTotals = function(item){
    var $grid = $('#treegrid');
  var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', item, false, 'sum') / 2;
  $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { item: colSum });
}

var getMonthName = function(){
    var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getMonth();
  return getMonthNameByIndex(n);
}

var getLastMonthName = function(){
    var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getMonth() - 1;
  if(n === -1){
    n = 12;
  }

  return getMonthNameByIndex(n);
}
var getMonthNameByIndex = function(index){
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June',
   'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
   return months[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **one** call of `footerData` method instead of multiple calls. It's more effective, first of all, and it's important because of the code of formatter of `faultsPerc` column uses the content of `outstandingFaults` and `totalFaults` properties of *the same row*. `footerData` method has 3 parameter. If you don't specify `false` as the last parameter then the data will be formatted with respect of formatters of the corresponding columns. Thus it's important that `outstandingFaults` and `totalFaults` properties will be defined in `footerData`.

```js
loadComplete: function() {
  var $grid = $(this);
  var colSumYearStart = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "yearStart", false, 'sum') / 2;
  var colSumLastMonth = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "lastMonth", false, 'sum') / 2;
  var colSumThisMonth = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "thisMonth", false, 'sum') / 2;
  var colSumOutstandingFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "outstandingFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
  var colSumOpenFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "openFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
  var colSumCloseFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "closeFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
  var colSumTotalFaults = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', "totalFaults", false, 'sum') / 2;
  var avePercentage = colSumOutstandingFaults / colSumTotalFaults * 100;
  $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', {
    name: "Total",
    yearStart: colSumYearStart,
    lastMonth: colSumLastMonth,
    thisMonth: colSumThisMonth,
    outstandingFaults: colSumOutstandingFaults,
    openFaults: colSumOpenFaults,
    closeFaults: colSumCloseFaults,
    totalFaults: colSumTotalFaults,
    faultsPerc: avePercentage
  });
}
```

Additionally you can consider to use `jsonmap` instead of custom formatter:

```
{ name: 'faultsPerc', formatter: "currency", width: 80,
    formatoptions: { suffix: "%", decimalPlaces: 0 },
    align: "right", sorttype: "integer",
    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] },
    jsonmap: function (item) {
        return Math.round(item.outstandingFaults / item.totalFaults * 100);
    }
}
```

`jsonmap` will "gets" the `faultsPerc` property from the input data and save it in the local item data. You can then use *any standard formatter*, like `formatter: "currency"`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ttc83khL/9/